# Is there any way to fill gap between trim and wall in bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, trim

Is there any way to fill these gaps between the wall and trim in my bathroom? The wall bows out and I did an admittedly bad job of cutting. These are the worst spots and it’s not bad enough that I want to tear it down and buy new trim and start over, but I would like to make it better if anyone has any ideas. I thought maybe backing rod, caulking and paint to match, but not sure how that would go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As long as you use a paintable caulk and do a neat job, I can't see any reason that wouldn't work.

Comment: TBH, I'd seriously consider replacing the vertical piece in the 1st pic. Not only does the miter not meet up (admittedly not an easy task - ask a whole new question if you'd like on tips to make it easier), but the vertical side where it meets the tile looks like it's been damaged by an errant saw or a few whacks with a hammer or something.

Answer (score 3):

Caulking before paint (with a paintable caulking) is the usual method.

Backer rod is normally only needed if the gap is huge. Which some of these might be, I guess.